# decode and encode with argonaut

Tags: scala, spray, argonaut

I would like to use  the public API of guildWars2 and decode and encode some informations . I am searching for  the decode and encode withs argonauts but I did not understand well .can you explain to me the fact of using argonaut. thanks

Comment: Have you seen [Argonaut docs](http://argonaut.io/doc/)? Specially the [docs about codecs](http://argonaut.io/doc/codec/)?

Comment: Ok I will see the documentation , but I want an example of application.

Comment: You can see some examples here: https://github.com/argonaut-io/argonaut/tree/master/argonaut/src/test/scala/argonaut/example

Comment: how can I consume a public rest API and access to its resources ?

Comment: @imen Don't mix concerns if you don't have to. Use some HTTP client library to get the data, and then parse it with some JSON library.