# Consuming a public REST API using Argonaut

Tags: json, scala, spray, argonaut

I am new into Spray and Scala. I'm currently working with the public REST API of Guild Wars 2. I would like to consume some resources (like gathering all sell and buy orders on the trading post of an item named "Bolt of Damask"). I'm using Argonaut for the JSON decoding.

Could anyone please give me some pointers on how I could achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you checked Argonaut's documentation on parsing? http://argonaut.io/doc/parsing/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [decode and encode with argonaut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460608/decode-and-encode-with-argonaut)

Comment: I would like to extract the id of an item given its name in this URL : "http://api.gw2tp.com/1/bulk/items-names.json" . how can I proceed ?